# Confusion on a random variance theorem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, variance

I'm confused on how $E(X)^2\sum_{s∈S}p(s) = E(X)^2$ because $E(X) = \sum_{s∈S}p(s)X(s)$. Wouldn't $E(X)^2=(\sum_{s∈S}p(s)X(s))^2$?[image]

Comment: The passage says $$E(X)^2\sum_{s\in S}p(s)=E(X)^2$$ not $$E\left(X^2\right)\sum_{s\in S}p(s)=E(X)^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment:  For $S$ finite or countable,

$\sum_{s \in S} p(s) = 1.$ So $E(X)^2\sum_{s∈S}p(s) = E(X)^2 \times (1) = E(X)^2.$ You seem to be confusing $E(X)^2 = [E(X)]^2$ with $E(X^2).$

$E(X) = \sum_{s \in S}  X(s)p(s),$ as you say, provided the
sum converges absolutely.

$E(X^2) = \sum_{s \in S}  X^2(s)p(s).$

In general, one does $not$ have $E(X^2)$ equal to $[E(X)]^2.$

Example. Let $X \sim Binom(n = 3, p = 1/2).$

Possibly illuminating session in R:

```
 n = 3;  p = 1/2;  x = 0:n;  pdf = dbinom(x, n, p)
 tabl = cbind(x, pdf, prod.1=x*pdf, prod.2=x^2*pdf);  tabl

 ## x   pdf prod.1 prod.2           
 ## 0 0.125  0.000  0.000
 ## 1 0.375  0.375  0.375
 ## 2 0.375  0.750  1.500
 ## 3 0.125  0.375  1.125
 colSums(tabl)
 ##   x pdf prod.1 prod,2        
 ## 6.0 1.0    1.5    3.0 

 sum(pdf)
 ## 1
 mu = sum(x * pdf);  mu
  1.5  # E(X)
 n*p
 ## 1.5

 vr = sum((x - mu)^2 * pdf);  vr
 0.75  # V(X)
 n * p * (1-p)
 ## 0.75

 vr.2 = sum(x^2 * pdf) - mu^2;  vr.2
 ## 0.75  # V(X) = E(X^2) - mu^2
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to upload the corresponding picture for my question. I'm not sure if this affects your answer or not.

Comment: No, just anticipates my little R session with binomial example. For $X \sim Binom(3, 1/2),$ can you find $3 = E(X^2) \ne [E(X)]^2 = \mu^2 = 9/4?$